# Login on a Website using c# and HTTPrequest

Tags: c#, authentication, web, httprequest

I want to login on a website with HTTPrequest using c#. I already searched at google and in this forum but i still some problems. Heres my code:

```
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;

namespace BodytelConnection
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaktionslogik für MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        webBrowser1.Navigate("http://www.bodytel.com/");
    }


    private void loginBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string benutzername = textBox_benutzername.ToString();   // used just for test
        string passwort = textBox_passwort.ToString();
        string cookieHeader;
        passwort = changeString(passwort);
        benutzername = changeString(benutzername);

        HttpWebRequest req =                                                          (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("http://www.bodytel.com/");
        req.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1;rv:15.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/15.0)";
        req.Method = "POST";
        req.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";
        req.Headers.Add("Accept-Language: de-de,de;q=0.8,en-us;q=0.5,en;q=0.3");
        req.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate");
        req.Headers.Add("Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7");
        req.KeepAlive = true;
        req.Headers.Add("Keep-Alive: 300");
        req.Referer = "https://secure.bodytel.com/de/mybodytel.html";
        req.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
        req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

        byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("login=hans-neo@web.de%password=xxxxxstep=login");
        req.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
        using (Stream os = req.GetRequestStream())
        {
            os.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        }
        WebResponse resp = req.GetResponse();
        cookieHeader = resp.Headers["Set-cookie"];

        webBrowser1.Navigate("https://secure.bodytel.com/de/mybodytel.html");
    }

    private string changeString(string myString)
    {

        myString = myString.Replace("System.Windows.Controls.TextBox: " ,"");
        return myString;
    }


    }

}
```

I cant login to the website and i just dont know where the problem is. How can i login to this site?

Thank you ;)

Comment: Don't you need & instead of %? `login=hans-neo@web.de&password=xxxxx&step=login`. % is reserved in url encoding for hexadecimal value representations.

Comment: yeah you`re right :P didnt noticed that but it still don`t work. It always shows me wrong username and password. i also tried the username: hans-neo%40web.de (tamper told me that)

Comment: Try using Fiddler (http://www.fiddler2.com) to analyze the problem.

Comment: or better wireshark, as fiddler does some decoding automatically. So you don't see the actual data transmitted in some cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem.

Here's the code:

```
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;
using System.Web;

namespace BodytelConnection{
/// <summary>
/// Interaktionslogik für MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        webBrowser1.Navigate("http://www.bodytel.com/");
    }

    private void textBox_benutzername_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void textBox_passwort_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void loginBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string benutzername = textBox_benutzername.ToString();
        string passwort = textBox_passwort.ToString();
        string cookieHeader;
        passwort = changeString(passwort);
        benutzername = changeString(benutzername);

        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("https://secure.bodytel.com/de/mybodytel.html");
        CookieContainer cookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
        request.CookieContainer = cookieContainer;

        request.Method = "POST";
        string postData = "login=hans-neo@web.de&password=xxxxx&step=login";
        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
        Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
        dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
        dataStream.Close();
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        string Text = "";

        foreach (Cookie cook in response.Cookies)
        {
            Text += "COOKIE: " + cook.Name + " = " + cook.Value + "\r\n";

        }
        request.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
        dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
        string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
        reader.Close();
        dataStream.Close();
        response.Close();

        webBrowser1.Navigate("https://secure.bodytel.com/de/mybodytel.html");
    }

    private string changeString(string myString)
    {

        myString = myString.Replace("System.Windows.Controls.TextBox: ", "");
        return myString;
    }


}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Asuming there's nothing wrong with SSL and you actually receive a valid response from the server, you could try to properly encode your values:

```
string loginstr = string.Format("login={0}&password={1}&step=login",
    HttpUtility.UrlEncode("hans-neo@web.de"),
    HttpUtility.UrlEncode("xxxxx"));
byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(loginstr);
```

Comment: where do you get HttpUtility?

Comment: i already imported System.Web;
but i cant find HttpUtility. Im using .NET 4.5

Comment: Okay i used System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode now which should be the same. Still dont work :( Thanks for your fast answers :)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using the wrong URL to login. When I use the login-form in chrome and look at what it sends out it looks like this:

[Chrome Networktab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dVpXm.png)

So its logging in over "https://secure.bodytel.com/de/mybodytel.html". I dont know if HttpWebRequest can manage SSL-Connections just like that, but you will need to use this link when creating the WebRequest object.

Comment: and what's the difference with the url from the OP? `req.Referer = "https://secure.bodytel.com/de/mybodytel.html";`

Comment: I think if SSL fails, `HttpWebRequest` would throw a `WebException` or `IOException`

Comment: I am not entirely sure about the Referer-Header, but I'd imagine if he connects using http://www.bodytel.com/, it wont be an SSL connection. In any case, his request does differ from the one sent by Chrome, so if he is looking to find the mistake, I think he should first try to send it exactly as the browser does. If that doesnt work he can worry about SSL failing.