# Open and automatically log into a website using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, web

I would like to load up a web page and log in straight away, by clicking the start button in Visual studio using C#.

I have used the Watin framework but cannot seem to get the code to work.

I have also got this code to open a URL:

```
string url = "http://www.google.com";   
System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();    
System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo(url);   
proc.StartInfo = startInfo;    
proc.Start();
```

Which only opens up a web page, but I am unsure of how to enter log in details automatically. Could anyone help me out? Thanks in advance!

Below is the code I tried to use from Watin which did not work, it loaded up a web page but just gave the local host. Not the site I wanted to navigate to:

```
public void SearchForWatiNOnGoogle()
{
  using (var browser = new IE("http://www.google.com"))
  {
    browser.TextField(Find.ByName("q")).TypeText("WatiN");
    browser.Button(Find.ByName("btnG")).Click();

    Assert.IsTrue(browser.ContainsText("WatiN"));
  }
}
```

I used the correct references and there were no build errors, it just loads the wrong page. Even when I tried to create the project in a test environment it still done the same thing.

Anyone who knows how to open a web page and log in automatically that would be great.

Comment: Please post what you tried with the Watin framework

Comment: Is this to use as an automated test, or for something else?

Comment: The way you're opening the web page is simply by telling windows to open an URL with the default browser. I doubt you can affect the browser at all like this since process will only accept standard input.

Comment: What is the significance of the code you have provided? This is not how WatiN is mean to be used.

Comment: You may want to look into this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12279014/login-on-a-website-using-c-sharp-and-httprequest it may have something for you to start with. Watin is a Webpage testing framework

Comment: Do you control the website?

Comment: I agree with @Campl3r. Maybe you can create an exe that does like Campl3r said and start that process. In that case you might need to have  auth cookie ane ect.

Comment: Thanks for the comments so far. Basically I want open a web page, log in automatically using c# code in a web app in visual studio. Firstly is this possible? And secondly how would I go about doing that? I will edit my question and show the Watin code I tried to use.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use it for automated UI testing you can use Coded Ui Tests. You can use MTM (Microsoft Test Manager) to record the steps and then generate the code using Coded Ui Tests. Once generated you can run it as many times you want. I haven't used WatIn but I think its possible to do the same record and generate code in WatIn as well.

When you record you will be manually performing the actions so you can enter the username/pwd and hit the Login button. You can later on configure the login credentials so that if they change you don't need to regenerate the test.

How to record and play back manual tests:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd286714.aspx

How to: Create a Coded UI Test:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd286681(v=vs.100).aspx

If you are not looking to do automated UI Testing then WatIn and Coded Ui Tests are not

Comment: Thanks for the answer, although it is not testing I am looking for. I just want to create the automatic log in from a web app. I wanted to implement the process in a website afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

2 possibilities, even though you aren't doing this for testing you could use selenium.

But it sounds like what you want is a [web browser control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in windows forms.