# Login to website programatically using using C#

Tags: c#, web-scraping

I want to login to this website using C#: Here is my attempt but its sending me to first page. Not returning me the next page, that should be visible after login, please help me to resolve this:

```
string formParams = 
string.Format("mail={0}&password={1}", store@admin.com", "admin");
      string cookieHeader;
      WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create("http://muslimgowns.com/dashboard/login/public_login");
            req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            req.Method = "POST";
            byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(formParams);
            req.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
            using (Stream os = req.GetRequestStream())
            {
                os.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            }
            WebResponse resp = req.GetResponse();
            cookieHeader = resp.Headers["Set-cookie"];
            using (StreamReader sr = new  StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                string pageSource = sr.ReadToEnd();
                File.AppendAllText("first.txt", pageSource);
            }

            string pageSource1;
            string getUrl = "http://muslimgowns.com/dashboard/home";
            WebRequest getRequest = WebRequest.Create(getUrl);
            getRequest.Headers.Add("Cookie", cookieHeader);
            WebResponse getResponse = getRequest.GetResponse();
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(getResponse.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                pageSource1 = sr.ReadToEnd();
                File.AppendAllText("second.txt", pageSource1);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Did you use e.g. Fiddler or TamperData (Firefox) to see what requests actually are sent to the server before the home page is displayed? You may want to look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31585606/checking-if-website-is-working-and-login/31617770#31617770) answer as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the first `GET` request to `public_login` returns an amount of cookies, and the `POST` request with credentials afterwards must be sent to `login_access` instead of `public_login`

The use of an `HttpWebRequest` instead of `WebRequest` and by setting the cookie container of it helps, and actually the server responds with `HTTP 302 Redirect` to the `POST` request and the `HttpWebRequest` automatically follows this redirection and downloads the dashboard.

Always use an http tracing tool like Fiddler or Wireshark or Network Monitor or developer tools of your browser to see what is received (cookies, headers etc.) and what is sent back. That's how I got all this.

Here is the fix:

```
string formParams = string.Format("mail={0}&password={1}", "store@admin.com", "admin");

CookieContainer cookieContainer = new CookieContainer();

HttpWebRequest req = WebRequest.CreateHttp("http://muslimgowns.com/dashboard/login/public_login");
req.CookieContainer = cookieContainer;
req.GetResponse(); // This is just to get the initial cookies returned by the public_login

req = WebRequest.CreateHttp("http://muslimgowns.com/dashboard/login/login_access");
req.CookieContainer = cookieContainer; // Set the cookie container which contains the cookies returned by the public_login

req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
req.Method = "POST";

byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(formParams);
req.ContentLength = bytes.Length;

using (Stream os = req.GetRequestStream())
{
    os.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
}

WebResponse resp = req.GetResponse();

using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream()))
{
    string pageSource = sr.ReadToEnd();
    File.AppendAllText("first.txt", pageSource); // Dashboard is returned.
}
```

Comment: this is perfect answer by Oguz Ozgul

Comment: Thank you :) The important part of this answer is not the fix for this specific case. I think the most important part is the recommendation of using an Http Analyzer to see the requested resources and request/response details which will help you with further development

Comment: yes, Im trying Http Analyzer. I am new to this and facing some issues as well. Can you please guide me, how I can login to fastundercar.com. Following urls Im trying. To login: http://www.fastundercar.com/ThemeLanding/Default28.aspx and after login: http://www.fastundercar.com/SiteManagement/UISettings/DisplayHtml.aspx
Also is there any way to pass hidden fields along with user and password info. If yes then what would be the syntax.

thank you in advance

Comment: Passing hidden fields is no different than passing the credentials. The query string format (key1=value1&key2=value2&hidden1=hiddenvalue1) is the format for all the form elements. I can't help you with any more sites, but you can analyze the request headers & body of the http requests and responses using your analyzer and try to simulate the same with C#

Comment: Hello

I am getting HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily response, when I am trying to login to a  site. Http Analyzer show that request was sent to inner page after login but after its redirected to login page again. any idea?

Comment: You should compare the web browser and the C# requests for other header parameters as well, like user agent, referer etc. I think the referer is probably correct, then the site is blocking unknown browsers may be.